# Bacula backup -- Restore

Tags: bacula

I'm in the path of working with Bacula, and I found this contradiction/confusion. Or what worse, a lack of theory for me.

I have been backing up a complete directory in Linux OS. Full backup, then Differential for a couple of weeks. It surprised me that if a dir/file has been deleted, in the next backup the dir/file still there. In examining the contents of the backup job I can still see files or dir that have been deleted from the target dir.

Has this something to do with "accurate mode"? Do I have to use this option?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand how these types of backups work. From the description, they are doing as documented.

I suggest you look up synthetic backup. It’s in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use Accurate Backup to track deleted files/dirs during Differential or Incremental backups.